# Not able to send data from opc ua prosys simulator server to opc publisher and then send it to iot hub

Tags: azure-iot-hub, opc-ua, azure-iot-edge

I have created IOT Hub in azure portal and then I added iot edge device and Inside that I have created three modules edge hub,edge agent and opc publisher from azure market place

In the opc publisher log I can see that endpoint is connected but I am not able to see device to cloud message in iot hub it is always zero
these are my configuration for opc publisher in Iot edge

```
{
    "Hostname": "OPCPublisher",
    "Cmd": [
        "PkiRootPath=/appdata/pki", 
        "--lf=/appdata/publisher.log", 
        "--pf=/appdata/publishednodes.json",
        "--aa",
        "--di=60",
        "--me=Json",
        "--mm=PubSub"
    ],
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": [
            "/c/IoTEdgeMapping:/appdata"
        ]
    }
}
```

moreover I am not using any environment variables in opc publisher. in Iot edge hub and iot edge agent I have made environment variables as upseteamProtocol:AMQPWS

```
DIAGNOSTICS INFORMATION for          :  (OPC Publisher 2.9.0.1)
2023-07-21 13:09:14   # Time                               : 2023-07-21T07:39:14.4554649Z
2023-07-21 13:09:14   # Ingestion duration                 :    00:00:00:48 (dd:hh:mm:ss)
2023-07-21 13:09:14   # Ingress DataChanges (from OPC)     :             10 (All time ~0.21/s; 10 in last 60s ~0.21/s)
2023-07-21 13:09:14   # Ingress EventData (from OPC)       :              0
2023-07-21 13:09:14   # Ingress ValueChanges (from OPC)    :             10 (All time ~0.21/s; 10 in last 60s ~0.21/s)
2023-07-21 13:09:14   # Ingress Events (from OPC)          :              0
2023-07-21 13:09:14   # Ingress BatchBlock buffer size     :              0
2023-07-21 13:09:14   # Encoding Block input/output size   :              0 | 0
2023-07-21 13:09:14   # Encoder Notifications processed    :             10
2023-07-21 13:09:14   # Encoder Notifications dropped      :              0
2023-07-21 13:09:14   # Encoder IoT Messages processed     :             11
2023-07-21 13:09:14   # Encoder avg Notifications/Message  :              1
2023-07-21 13:09:14   # Encoder worst Message split ratio  :              0
2023-07-21 13:09:14   # Encoder avg IoT Message body size  :            480
2023-07-21 13:09:14   # Encoder avg IoT Chunk (4 KB) usage :            0.1
2023-07-21 13:09:14   # Estimated IoT Chunks (4 KB) per day:              0
2023-07-21 13:09:14   # Outgress input buffer count        :              0
2023-07-21 13:09:14   # Outgress input buffer dropped      :              0
2023-07-21 13:09:14   # Outgress IoT message count         :             11 (0.2/s)
2023-07-21 13:09:14   # Connection retries                 :              1
2023-07-21 13:09:14   # Opc endpoint connected?            :           True
2023-07-21 13:09:14   # Monitored Opc nodes succeeded count:              1
2023-07-21 13:09:14   # Monitored Opc nodes failed count   :              0
```

this is my opc publisher logs

I am using [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/industrial-iot/tutorial-data-explorer-import) to build this

moreover I am using UA TCP protocol

and my publishednodes.json is

```
[
  {
    "EndpointUrl": "opc.tcp://myipaddress:53530/OPCUA/SimulationServer",
    "UseSecurity": false,
    "OpcNodes": [
      {
        "Id": "i=2258",
        "OpcSamplingInterval": 2000,
        "OpcPublishingInterval": 5000,
        "DisplayName": "Current time"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

what am I doing wrong? how to send data from opc ua server to opc publisher and then to iot hub?

Answer (score 0):

you are most likely missing routes on the IoT Edge device. The Device-to-cloud messages in IoT Edge device is handled by IoT Edge Hub that acts as a local broker and propagates messages to the cloud. To process messages using routes set up a route to send messages coming from an endpoint (module or device) to the input endpoint which could be your IoT Hub.

If you named the OPC Publisher module as `publisher`, here is what your route should look like if you would like to push data to IoT Hub `FROM /messages/modules/publisher/* INTO $upstream`. Please refer the below image for more reference.

[image]

Please refer the documentation [How OPC Publisher works](https://azure.github.io/Industrial-IoT/opc-publisher/#how-opc-publisher-works) for additional guidance and the steps needed to configure the OPC publisher module.

I would also like to point that your binds section points to the directory `"/c/IoTEdgeMapping:/appdata"`. I am not sure if you are trying to set up the module on an [EFLOW device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/iot-edge-for-linux-on-windows?view=iotedge-1.4). If this is not an EFLOW device and you still could not see the data transmitted, try going with the default directories mentioned in the article and see if that helps.